# What is the use of "query_cache_wlock_invalidate" in MySql Query Cache?

Tags: mysql

While adding a concept of MySql Query Cache we have a parameter called "query_cache_wlock_invalidate", I wanted to know what is the use of this parameter.

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the description [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_wlock_invalidate)? What part of it is not clear?

Comment: @Barmar , i am a bit poor with understanding , would appreciate if you can explain with the layman language.

Comment: Do you understand how the query cache works in general, or do you need that explained first?

Comment: yeah  i have implemented it in my local . which is working fine

Answer (score 3):

When you make a query that's in the query cache, normally the cached will be returned, even if the query uses a table that another client has locked because it's modifying the table. But if you set this option, it will not use the query cache in this case, it will wait for the other client to finish what they're doing and unlock the table. This ensures that you get the most up-to-date results; using the cache would return old table contents.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_wlock_invalidate) linked by @Barmar, `query_cache_wlock_invalidate` controls what are commonly referred to as **[dirty reads](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dbms-dirty-read-in-sql/)**.

The default is 0/OFF, which means that dirty reads are permitted. This is generally not considered good practice for strict transaction-processing integrity, and that is why dirty reads are disabled by default in most enterprise-grade RDBMS'.

If you are okay returning slightly-stale data, dirty reads are fine and can improve concurrency. But when database semaphores are essential to serializing access to shared data -- thereby preventing race conditions in busy row "hot spots" -- dirty reads should always be disabled.