# MySQL writes probably not updating query cache

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-5.6, query-cache

I have a strange problem.

On MySQL 5.6 I have query cache enabled, with the below settings.
[image]

The idea of caching is that whenever a write operation happens, the record is invalidated (removed) and created upon next read.

However, I do get the stale data a lot of the times, and it gets corrected when I change some characters in the query.

I know turning off query cache is certainly an option that works, but am I doing something wrong here in terms of settings related to query cache?

I read about write-through caching, but couldn't find any default implementation of it in MySQL nor does it mention anywhere about the invalidations clearly.

Another important point is - I do have a lot of connection objects live at any point of time (a few tens), is it possible that my issue is because of some caching at connection level (if possible) instead of global cache?

EDIT - NOT a duplicate question to

[What is the use of "query_cache_wlock_invalidate" in MySql Query Cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320261/what-is-the-use-of-query-cache-wlock-invalidate-in-mysql-query-cache)

because here the issue is that the cached value is being returned even after a long time after the write happened, as expectation is that the write resulted in cache invalidation anyways as the lock would have also been given up by then.

EDIT -

`query_cache_wlock_invalidate` actually worked. The issue was with incorrect logging of write timestamp which resulted in invalid conclusion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the use of "query\_cache\_wlock\_invalidate" in MySql Query Cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320261/what-is-the-use-of-query-cache-wlock-invalidate-in-mysql-query-cache)

Comment: NOT a duplicate question to 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320261/what-is-the-use-of-query-cache-wlock-invalidate-in-mysql-query-cache

because here the issue is that the cached value is being returned even after a long time after the write happened, as expectation is that the write resulted in cache invalidation anyways as the lock would have also been given up by then.

Comment: Sorry, it's easier to believe user error than a major bug in MySQL query cache. Please provide evidence of your assertion, then enable `query_cache_wlock_invalidate` and demonstrate the issue recurs.

Comment: Sure will enable ``query_cache_wlock_invalidate`` and share an update here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `query_cache_wlock_invalidate` to `ON` works.